# How do I create UITableView with Navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm very, very, very new to iOS development. I'm trying to create a control like in the attached picture, where user can tap on the item, the software navigates to a view with a list and then from here the user can choose an option.

[image]

Any ideas how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More precisely Grouped UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very wide as it's the whole new thing you want to learn(No woories ;-).... Welcome to the team). It will be quite lengthy if I explain it here. Better option is to go to the following site which explains it quite neatly.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

And to navigate to different view you have to put your code in didSelectRowAtIndexpath method of UITableView. And there you can code something like this to go to the different ViewController

```
   SecondViewController *secondView=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableVIew, [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/) and [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) will help you :)

Also, Apple documentation for [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UITableViewController to create the above screens. You can use the tutorials available to know how to create the UITableView. Here how your views will look like :

[image]